# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory. I know this kind of question is there. But they didn't helped

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

I use macOS Catalina 10.15.4.
Actually there was a problem when I wanted to make the migration. then it solved when I did my migration using xampp terminal. But when I added this code. To my PostController. There appear this error.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

I fixed all in .env file. And config/database.php file. But it didn't work too.

Comment: What database are you using? Can you also post your .env file?

Comment: You're most likely trying to use sqlite as your database, and you've not created an sqlite file in the database directory of your laravel app

Comment: @Douwe de Haan
`
APP_NAME=Laravel 
APP_ENV=local 
APP_KEY=base64:zHNH5VOvOC4tRV7D9MqoSMgRijlXXPIn9aT2EKiUhNw= 
APP_DEBUG=true 
APP_URL=http://localhost 

LOG_CHANNEL=stack 

DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=localhost 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=laravel_blog 
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=asdasd`

Comment: Please, edit your question and add more information. Looks like your database are not encountered. You need to put the default database information on your `database.conf` and your model to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is an error, in version of XAMPP. And I think it is because of lack of information in apachefriends.org. When you start to download there is any info about that the version is VM version, and in that way they the linked hyperlink to download VM version. Only after declining, and entering to "sourceforge". You can see that it is VM version. For fixing this error I downloaded Installer version. 
It is extremely negligence from authors of apachefriends.